# Where is the surface emission for materials to create a light source from a plane?

Tags: materials, light

Im currently trying to create a light source from a mesh plane, and a tuturiol explains that i need to add a material and then select surface>emission>strenght 10. I can't seem to find a way to edit surface in 2.72b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Cycles:

**Method 1:**

1. Set the render engine to cycles
2. Go into the node editor
3. Check *Use Nodes*
4. Delete the *Diffuse Node* <kbd>X</kbd>

*Click images for larger versions*
[image]

**Method 2:**

1. Set the render engine to cycles
2. Go into the *materials panel*
3. Click *Use Nodes*
4. Change the *Surface* to Emission

[image]

## Internal:

1. Check that you're using internal
2. Go into the *materials panel*
3. Set the emit value
4. Check shadeless (to look like cycles)

[image]

Comment: wow thanks for the quick response..you rock!

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Note that that functionality is part of the *Node efficiency tools* addon.